# «Тепель-тапель» — значение, употребление

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, значение-слов, неологизмы

*«Вот ловкач!» — закричало человеческое стадо, и некто Зубов разбежался и со всего маху двинулся головой о стенку. «Эх!» — вскрикнула баба с флюсом. Но Комаров сделал этой бабе **тепель-тапель**, и баба с воем убежала в подворотню.*
Д. Хармс. Начало очень хорошего летнего дня (симфония)

Вот что есть на [Грамоте](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C).

**Вопрос № 253576**
Подскажите пожалуйста: что значит *тепель-тапель*?
**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
Это авторское слово Даниила Хармса, без определенной связи с реальным словарным составом русского языка.

Вот примеры использования другими авторами.

*Ясно будущее вижу,

выпив «пару капель»:

всем дворцам помимо хижин

будет **тепель-тапель**!*
[В. Оден. Летопись Тэлы](https://books.google.ee/books?id=Eg7lCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT476&lpg=PT476&dq=%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C&source=bl&ots=JMiq-MKjkK&sig=ACfU3U3dRBvPCJebN_aZ3hByptJm-PkO9w&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiM45uqlJHjAhVspIsKHVfiBYk4ChDoATAHegQIBhAB#v=onepage&q=%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C&f=false)

*Филологическое образование, однако, брало свое, и он понимал эту эзотерическую концепцию в духе постмодернистского текстуализма. «Моя жизнь есть текст. Причем текст написанный, мягко говоря, отнюдь не самым талантливым автором. Да что там — **тепель-тапель**, а не текст! Ересь, какой свет не видывал! Что ни слово — то пафос; что ни строчка – то скука...»*
[В. Шильке, А. Шарипов. История ошибок](https://books.google.ee/books?id=HlCXCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT26&lpg=PT26&dq=%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%20%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%20%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C&source=bl&ots=azyJaqAhWg&sig=ACfU3U3OokFxC2tHBQzrRjELr-TjXbevKQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjXvs-6kpHjAhVKz6YKHVSLDo8Q6AEwBHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%20%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%20%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C&f=false)

Подскажите, правильно ли использовано слово "тепель-тапель" в приведенных текстах?
Каким вам видится его значение и употребление?
Встречалось ли вам это слово?

Answer (score 3):

Я бы рассмотрел это выражение с точки зрения *зауми* (без всякой негативной коннотации, а сугубо как литературного приема). *Заумь*, широко используемая в произведениях футуристов, и в частности Даниилом Хармсом, позволяет читателю с помощью аналогии "добирать" смысл в авторских конструкциях, которые сознательно нарушают один или несколько аспектов естественного языка.

***тепель-тапель*** относится, в большей степени, к  [морфологической зауми](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8C#%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B8):

> **морфологическая заумь**: существующие в языке морфемы (корни и аффиксы) сочетаются таким образом, что значение получающегося слова остается в значительной степени неопределённым;

и, в какой-то степени, к супрасинтаксической зауми:

> **супрасинтаксическая заумь**: при формальной, грамматической правильности конструкций, составленных из обычных слов, высокая степень неопределённости возникает на уровне референции — проще говоря, остается принципиально неясным, о чём идёт речь.

так как слово *тепель* можно все же найти в [Словаре синонимов Тришина](http://rus-yaz.niv.ru/doc/synonyms-trishin/fc/slovar-210-12.htm#zag-311112), а также оно является искажением слова *теперь* для не произносящего "р", например, Семена Ивановича Дергальского в "Леди Макбет Мценского уезда" Лескова ([Google Books](https://books.google.ca/books?id=6ONDAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA177&lpg=PA177&dq=%D0%9C%D0%BD%D1%A3+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C+%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83+%D0%B4%D1%A3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE:+%D1%8F+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8E+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%82%D1%96%D1%8E,+%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8A+%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8A+%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C:+%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%A3%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%82%D1%96%D1%8E.&source=bl&ots=svbDg6f9ch&sig=ACfU3U1gwS-8befCQK8_lB2BgbPv9J31JQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTxaegvJLjAhWlc98KHSqnAbAQ6AEwAXoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%9C%D0%BD%D1%A3%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D0%B4%D1%A3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%3A%20%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8E%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%82%D1%96%D1%8E%2C%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8A%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8A%20%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%3A%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%A3%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%82%D1%96%D1%8E.&f=false)) 1864:

> Мнѣ **тепель** одному дѣлать нецего: я собилаю палтію, и плисолъ васъ плосить: составимѣе палтію.

Исходя из этого, сложно делать вывод о правильном и неправильно употреблении слова, не входящего ни в один словарь. Тут скорее стоит опираться на то, насколько могут расходиться аналогии читателей при его прочтении в контексте.

Лично я ни разу не сталкивался с *тепель-тапелью* за пределами Даниила Хармса. В приведенных отрывках произведений других авторов явно чувствуются другие смыслы (или краски) вложенные в слово. Однако, мне кажется, употреблены они четко и лаконично выражают вложенную (или, как минимум, читаемую мной) мысль.

Answer (score 1):

Встречал это выражение только у Хармса. Когда искал его смысл, видел ту же информацию, мол, это авторское. Ваши примеры — это же современные тексты, авторы 
которых явно просто взяли выражение у Даниила Ивановича. Я думаю, что оно изначально так и задумано, как нечто неопределённое, но забавно звучащее, дабы каждый читатель додумал для себя. Если на то пошло, Хармс любит ничего не объяснять, писать так, будто всё берётся из ниоткуда. Это выражение, полагаю, тоже иррационального происхождения.